Data Migration of multiple tables from one database to other using Spring Boot and Spring Batch
I want to migrate from one database to other using Spring Batch and Spring Boot. I have learnt that we have to declare @Bean for step, Job, JobLauncher, ItemWriter, ItemReader. But for those beans to be created, the database url,username and password is to be declared in the application.properties file. But I want to create them dynamically. By this I mean that I will give the database details at runtime for example in api request body. Is this possible?. I tried coding it but giving a lot of errors. And I don't know the tables in the database. There are multiple schemas and tables.
I tried manually initializing all of these but failed. If anyone can share a good resource or answer for my usecase, I would be very glad.

you need to be more specific and also add code

I can't add any code because it is full of errors and I think it wouldn't be of any help. And to be more specific, Is dynamic/runtime declaration of datasources and for tables(entities) , I tried Map<String,Object>. I just wanted to ask is it possible? :)
PS: I'm just a beginner in spring boot and batch
